# SKScene access property variable from another

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit

I've got

Action.m

```
-(void)importLevel{
    menu *startMenu = (menu *)self.scene.view.window.rootViewController;
    _level = startMenu.level;
    NSLog(@"LEVEL:");
    NSLog(@"%f", _level);
}
```

And menu.h

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) float level;
```

I know that something is wrong with `self.scene.view.window.rootViewController` but I couldnt find any resoultion

Comment: What is `menu`? What is `Action`? It's always better to post more code rather than less...

Comment: menu and Action are SKScene files

Comment: @user3370412 in that way you're not loading a SKScene but a ViewController

Comment: _tuStartMenu *startMenu = (_tuStartMenu *)self.scene; dont work too.